# Passing mutable objects around atomically in actor hierarchy

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, transactions, akka

I have built a proper actor hierarchy for my Scala/Java application that is relies mostly on fire-forget semantics. I am now faced with the need to pass unique mutable objects atomically between actors. In particular, I have three actors, A, B and C:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

B and C both have their own *Map* of unique *Objects* and do not know about each other. At some point in time, B will decide that it needs to get rid of object *O*. **I am looking for a mechanism that allows for object *O* to be added to *C*'s *Map* and removed from *B*'s *Map* atomically**

*B* does not decide that it is *C* that will receive object *O*: all it does at first is sending a disposal request to actor *A*. Actor *A* can allow or refuse the disposal request from *B* and from there introduce or not *C* to actor *B* for them to conclude the transaction autonomously and atomically.

**EDIT**

My original question is ill-labeled and confused. In my system messages *are* immutable: I send UUIDs between actors, not refs to objects. These UUIDs are the keys to a private per-actor map of mutable objects. The usage of objects held by both B and C in their private map are is meant to be mutually exclusive at any given point in time.

It is trivial for me to go one step further and make sure no mutable object is ever shared between B and C, that is, to make sure key K in B's map and key K in C's map point to different private mutable objects (say Ob and Oc) having the same UUID.

One goal is to avoid doing calculations on object Ob in B and Oc in C at the same time. This is not really a problem in itself (I don't mind wasting a few CPU cycles once in a while during a transition from actor B to actor C), but it becomes a problem since actors B and C report their simulation results to a 3rd party client that we can call D.

D does not know about the relationship between A, B and C, and it could therefore receive results from B and C about the same UUID, not being able to tell which one it should listen to. Due to the nature of the simulation, these results could be different and conflicting. Of course, actor B could stop simulating object Ob and send a message to actor C telling it to start the simulation on object Oc. That would prevent client D to receive messages from both B and C about the same object, but there would be a time frame during which this UUID could be absent from the simulation altogether. Perhaps this is not very important for my application but I still have to verify this. The ideal for me would be a synchronized switch of actor for a UUID.

Comment: I am not asking for someone to create the actor code for me: all I need is the bit about atomically removing an element from one map and adding it to another. This is the bit of code I cannot provide, for it is the question itself.

Comment: I don't see the reason for the need for atomicity in your question, could you elaborate please?

Comment: These objects I'm passing around have mutable state and represent bodies in a simulation. An actor owning one is responsible for simulating it. It is unacceptable to have a body be simulated by both of these actors (B and C) at the same time (or by none), therefore requiring atomicity in this transaction.

Comment: Messages should be immutable.

Comment: Could you route O to B or C in advance? There will be no trouble. Also if you find in B that O requires C-handling, you may send the object O to A (removing it from B and putting it temporarily to A) and then A will forward it to C.

Answer (score 1):

[Two phase commit protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) can be used to do atomic update.

```
B -> A tell ("initiate moving of O B->C") 

A -> B tell ("prepare remove O") //
A -> C tell ("prepare add O") // (A selects C)

C changes O to prepare-to-add state
C -> A tell ("ready to add O")

B changes O to prepared-to-remove state.
B -> A tell ("ready to remove O")

A waits for two "ready" messages and then:
A -> B, C tell ("commit")

if A receives timeout, then
A -> B, C tell ("rollback")
```

To make this protocol work reliably you need to implement undo/redo logs in B,C.

Answer (score 1):

[ScalaSTM](http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/quick_start.html) can make implementation of the protocol easier. I'm not pretty sure, but the following may give some hints how to achieve the goal:

```
class O { val owner = Ref(None:Option[ActorRef]) }

class A extends Actor {
  val listOfTransferedObject = mutable.ListBuffer()
  def move(O, to) {
    atomic { implicit txn =>
      val oldOwner = O.owner()
      O.owner() = self 
      listOfTransferedObject += O
      oldOwner.get ! NotifyRemoved(O) // you may prefer to use `ask` 
      O.owner() = to
      O.owner().get ! NotifyAdded(O) // you may prefer to use `ask` 
    }
  }
}
```

In receive of B and C you only need to update internal maps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can accomplish what you are trying to do using Transactors.

Specifically, B and C should include the `Transactor` trait. B should implement the `coordinate` method such that when A sends a message introducing it to C and telling it to go ahead and update its state, B invites C to participate in the transaction by calling `include(C)`. Both actors should implement the `atomically` method to handle the actual updates to their internal state (i.e., updating their Maps).

Something like this:

```
type Key = // your map key type
type Value = // your map value type

case class AtomicallyTransferObject(transferTo : ActorRef, key : Key, value : Value)

class B extends Actor with Transactor
{
   private val myMap = mutable.Map[Key, Value]

   def coordinate = {
      case AtomicallyTransferObject(transferTo, key, value) => include(transferTo)
   }

   def atomically = {implicit txn =>
      case AtomicallyTransferObject(_, key, value) => myMap -= (key, value)
   }
}

class C extends Actor with Transactor
{
   private val myMap = mutable.Map[Key, Value]

   def atomically = {implicit txn =>
      case AtomicallyTransferObject(self, key, value) => myMap += (key, value)
   }
}
```

Actor A would send an `AtomicallyTransferObject` message to B, which would cause B to invite C to join the transaction, then both actors would process the message atomically.

More information on Transactors can be found here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/transactors.html

Note that for non-transactional messages, instead of implementing `receive`, you should implement `normally`, since the `Transactor` trait provides an implementation of `receive` that delegates to `normally` and `atomically`.